# How to remove border in IE edge around special characters?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, special-characters

This is how my cross button looks in IE/Edge:

[image]

This is how it should look:

[image]

CSS inspector shows FFF color for this #10006; html character:

[image]

How can I remove black border and set color to white?

Comment: Please provide further details about the markup and styling for your button. Is it an SVG? A font?

Comment: This is #10006; html character as its written in the question.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. I will add an answer for you shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my tests IE adds the border to a number of unicode characters from the UTF-8 dingbats subset. This might be a shortcoming of the font being used to render the character (possibly Arial Unicode MS?).

If you want to reliably use the `#10006` entity you may need to use a web font that includes that character. Here is a fiddle that loads DejaVu Sans and will display the `#10006` entity in Edge: https://jsfiddle.net/ekwtwv11/

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'DejaVuSans';
  src: url(dejavusans-webfont.woff);
}
.utf10006 {
  font-family: 'DejaVuSans', 'Arial Unicode MS', sans-serif;
}
```

However there are other options that may be preferable:

- Use `#215;` which is supported by most fonts
- Use an SVG shape
- Use `:before` and `:after` pseudo selectors to create an "x" on your button:

```
<div class="btn"></div>

.btn {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.btn:before,
.btn:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 6px;
  top: 16px;
  display: block;
  background: white;
  width: 28px;
  height: 8px;
}
.btn:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.btn:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Here is a demo showing that last technique: https://jsfiddle.net/2p9ufxt7/

Comment: my respect for detailed answer!